# StartsWith does not return true

Tags: c#

I have a small issue with startswith.

```
string[] MatchedFiles = Directory
    .GetFiles(this.sReportDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith(this.sProjectNumber + "_InputCounts", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();
```

I need to filter few more files but it does not even work with one. Array is always empty! However, it works with contains?

I have tried all string comparisons.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Or is there better way of getting file counts with multiple filters other then going trough the array of all files?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post you code here - site rules are post code here, not somewhere else as otherwise the elsewhere could go and then your question makes no sense

Comment: Even with the code the question makes no sense - we would also need examples of the file names in the fiolders.

Comment: What is `sReportDirectory`? What is `sProjectNumber`? What are the directory names? This question is unanswerable.

Comment: Well, have you debugged that code to see some exemplary combinations of values for `s` on the one hand, and `this.sProjectNumber + "_InputCounts"` on the other hand? Can you post any such examples here?

Comment: Have you looked at the list of files produced without filtering?

Comment: I'm betting that every file starts with something like `"C:\"`.

Comment: I need to know how many files are starting with specific string(for example 9999_InputCounts* or 8888_OutputCounts*) in a specified directory and all sub folders.

Comment: Ok sorry let me make it clearer. sReportDirectory = "J:\\PROD\Projects\99999 Project Test\" where sProject number = "99999". I need to locate any file that starts with sProjectNumber_InputCounts or sProjectNumber_OutputCounts

Comment: You should really investigate more before asking here (like, look at the results of `GetFiles()` which makes the answer trivial). You also had a hint (`Contains()` yields results). What kept you?

Comment: I do  not want to use contains as it a bit less save from my point of view. There might be other files where the same combination might be present in the middle of a file name

Comment: @TomPisz - Peter gave you `.Contains(...)` as a hint. He's trying to get you to think about the problem - he's not suggesting that you use `.Contains(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

[`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the full path to the file so you'll have to strip away the path first. e.g. with [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] MatchedFiles = Directory
    .GetFiles(this.sReportDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(s => Path.GetFileName(s).StartsWith(this.sProjectNumber + "_InputCounts", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: So the only way is to manually filter the array to get the file counts?

Comment: @TomPisz That, or you go with henningbenks solution to have the `GetFiles` method filter it. Since your filter is simple enough that would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Should work using the pattern directly:

```
string[] MatchedFiles = Directory
.GetFiles(this.sReportDirectory, this.sProjectNumber + "_InputCounts*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.ToArray();
```

Comment: My origianal code was this http://pastebin.com/Q0tPRJ6x. This worked fine and was giving me the right number. However, since then I have discovered I need to cater for other files names hence the the attempt of using the StartWith.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use the full path in the StartsWith method:

```
string[] MatchedFiles = Directory
.GetFiles(this.sReportDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(s => s.StartsWith(this.sReportDirectory + "\\" + this.sProjectNumber + "_InputCounts", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
.ToArray();
```

Comment: sReportDirectory = "J:\\PROD\\Projects\\99999 Project Test\\"

Comment: "Remove the backslash" -- or better use `Path.Combine()` which takes care of these issues, in a platform-independent manner.

Comment: Apologies all!! I have found what the problem was... so sill that I will not even mention lol. Thanks for all the replies.